# Adding/Removing Active Class Onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add an "active" class to the h3 with jQuery once the heading has been clicked and have it be removed when another h3 is clicked. I've tried a many examples here on stackoverflow but cannot get the class to add.

Here is an example of my code:

```
<div id="qa-faq0" class="qa-faq cf">
<h3 class="qa-faq-title"><a class="qa-faq-anchor" href="#">Frequently Asked Question #1</a></h3>

<div class="qa-faq-answer" style="display: none;"><p>Frequently Asked Question #1 Content Goes Here</p>

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the code for adding the class?

Comment: You should select an answer that you like.

Comment: @user3220314 http://jsfiddle.net/RKcmt/. For your other question.

Comment: Wow thanks! Sorry I'm a beginner to Stackoverflow and deleted the question because I couldn't figure out how to explain it better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/6ARUq/1/

```
$(function(){
    var $h3s = $('h3').click(function(){
        $h3s.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

OR http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/6ARUq/2/

```
$(function(){
    $('h3').click(function(){
        $('h3.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".qa-faq-title").click( function(){
    $(".qa-faq-title.active").removeClass("active");

    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

This will remove the active class when clicked then add it to the current item being clicked.

Comment: Delegation is not needed... Correct that and you'll have my upvote!

Comment: Delegation is removed, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

You can just toggle the class every time the header is clicked.

```
$(function () {
    $(".qa-faq-title").click(function () {
        $("h3.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: *"have it be removed when **another** h3 is clicked."* Your code doesn't do that.